# alr4 R package: UBSprices data not found

Tags: r, r-package

I have had issued getting UBSprices data loaded in **alr4 package**. Instead, I got the below error. Please, kindly suggest the way out.
Thanks

````
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘effects’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
Error: package ‘effects’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘alr4’ was built under R version 4.0.5 
2: package ‘car’ was built under R version 4.0.5 
3: package ‘effects’ was built under R version 4.0.5 
> data("UBSprices")
Warning message:
In data("UBSprices") : data set ‘UBSprices’ not found ```
````

Comment: don't know, but try `update.packages()` and/or `install.packages("Rcpp")`.  If those don't work, please provide the results of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Update `alr4`: https://rdrr.io/rforge/alr4/man/UBSprices.html

Comment: @BenBolker, I installed the Rcpp package, and I now have the dataset got loaded into the R workspace. Thanks for your help.